# Div element not aligning in the middle of another div element

Tags: css, html, block, vertical-alignment

This is my relevant page markup:

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="logo">
        <a href="/">Home</a>
    </div>
    <div id="user_box">
        test
    </div>
</div>
```

And my relevant CSS:

```
#header {
    width: 960px;
    height: 110px;
}

#logo {
    background: url('/assets/img/logo.png') no-repeat center;
    width: 300px;
    height: 110px;
    float: left;
}


#user_box {
    width: 300px;
    height: 60px;
    float: right;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Now, I want to position the `user_box` div in the vertical middle of the `header` div. After a lot of Google'ing and experimenting, I have learned that this isn't easy. Apparently, I can't vertical align a block element such as a div. So I'm looking for a different way to do this.

I saw the hacky `display: table;` method and tried using it, but it didn't change a thing. Also tried changing the element to an inline element like a `span`, but that didn't work either. I even tried using `margin: auto 0;` for some god awful reason, and that also didn't work at all.

So I'm asking for help. How do I vertically align this div inside my header div?

Thanks!

Comment: You'd want to use `display:table-cell;` instead so that you can attribute the `vertical-align:middle;` css property, but that display type messes with a lot of things.

Answer (score 0):

Set the line-height of `user_box` equal to the height of `header`

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/pyppD/

Comment: This only centers the text inside `#user_box`, instead of the actual div. See: http://jsfiddle.net/pyppD/1/

Comment: That's all you had inside `#user_box` to center :)

Answer (score 0):

vertical align doesn't work with divs its for aligning elements in tables. In your case you could just use this

```
    #user_box { margin-top:25px; } /*110-60 = 50/2 = 25*/
```

Answer (score 0):

So I fiddled around with your code a little bit, and here's what I got: http://jsfiddle.net/3k8XE/

As you can see I'm using a table as the header, and applying the same id to each element, except the two inner divs have changed to td's. I've added an inner td to compensate the space between the two divs since they were originally set to float:left/right.

(Of course the borders are just to show what's actually going on here.)